# Calling a SAS macro many times with values from a data set

Tags: sas

I'd like to call a macro many times using values from lines in some data set. For instance, if I have some set like this:

```
data inputs;
    input n stat type $2;
    datalines;
        134 4.543 A
        230 6.991 A
        1056 5.991 B
        97 6.33 C
        490 3.43 B
        ...
    ;
    run;
```

And I have some macro that I want to run on these values, like so:

```
%themacro(134,4.543,A)
%themacro(230,6.991,A)
%themacro(1056,5.991,B)
...
```

What are my best options for doing this? I've tried a few things that 
I haven't been able to quite get to work out.

Comment: CALL EXECUTE. The documentation has a pretty clear example and I've linked to a duplicate that does it as well.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know what to search for!